# Why would anyone choose to file for bankruptcy?

Tags: bankruptcy, default

A bankruptcy wipes out the debtor's resources to pay creditors. If one has some paid off property but defaults on some unsecured accounts why would he or she want to file for bankruptcy thus risking liquidation of his/her assets? What would be a rationale behind such a filing?

Comment: You are assuming consumers make rational decisions, they don't.

Answer (score 8):

> A bankruptcy wipes out the debtor's resources to pay creditors.

This is a bit of an overstatement. Bankruptcy comes in many forms. For individuals, the most common for is "Chapter 7", in which most of your debts are forgiven in exchange for a liquidation of assets to pay part of what's owed.  Secured loans (e.g. car loan) can be taken care of before bankruptcy by just surrendering the asset (repossession) and making up the difference.

A bankruptcy will require the borrower to liquidate *enough assets to pay off the debt*. One doesn't necessarily have to lose *everything*

> If one has some paid off property but defaults on some unsecured accounts why would he or she want to file for bankruptcy thus risking liquidation of his/her assets?

A house is typically exempt from liquidation if the borrower is current on the mortgage and doesn't have a lot of equity. There is also a "homestead exemption" that varies by state that can be used to protect a house in bankruptcy. But, if one has, say, a million dollar paid-off property, they will possibly have to liquidate it to pay off unsecured debt. I would suspect that is very uncommon, though. More than likely someone declaring bankruptcy will have little to no equity in their home that is well under the homestead exemption.

> What would be a rationale behind such a filing?

It is the last resort to recover from crushing debt. It stops debt collectors from coming after you, threatening to sue, and generally harassing you. It typically reduces the overall debt burden and gets rid of exorbitant interest and fees that may have piled up.

It can also prevent judgments from being filed on you by individual creditors, or remove existing judgments. A lawsuit would require you to show up in court (hopefully hire an attorney), and if a judgment is placed against you, the payments can be taken out of your paycheck (up to a certain amount depending on local laws).

It also put you back on the road to get back to credit recovery within a few years.

Comment: Suppose the debtor's house is paid off. Then declaring bankruptcy wouldn't be a reasonable option for the reason that the house would be under the peril of liquidation. Creditors' harassing and threats are meaningless and can easily be ignored.

Comment: Again, houses can be (and often are) exempt from liquidation if they're under the homestead exemption. And it's not just phone calls and letters - they can also file lawsuits, requiring you to show up in court and likely getting a judgment against you that can be taken from your wages automatically.  They are not easily ignored.

Comment: What if the debtor is self-employed and doesn't really care about garnishments? Another thing is that far not every house can be under the homestead exception.

Comment: Self-employed people get paychecks too, or they own a business that can _also_ be targeted by creditors.  A bankruptcy filing can _protect_ those assets from being taken away. You're reducing the premise to a very narrow situation, ignoring the much more common scenarios that benefit by bankruptcy.

Comment: A friend of mine is in this narrow situation. He owns a home outright, I don't think it's under the homestead protection. He is also self-employed, but doesn't have a business with assets that can be taken by creditors. Self-employed people are under total control when it comes to their pay. They can, for example, declare income as dividends.

Comment: So maybe bankruptcy is not the best option for your friend, then? Maybe your friend wants to pay off his.her debts and wants to use a bankruptcy as a way of dealing with all creditors at once?  Your friend should talk to a bankruptcy attorney and see what options are best for them. Your questions seems to question the viability of bankruptcy _in general_, not in a very specific case.

Comment: It sounds sounds like they have some financial support that indicates that they should just pay off their debts, not try to get out of them through a bankruptcy.

Comment: Can you please clarify about wanting to pay off his/her debts and use bankruptcy as a way of dealing with all creditors at once? Sorry, I didn't get that.

Comment: @sequence , everything you are saying in the comments is 1000% correct.  YES, if you own assets (say, a house) and there is NOT an exemption in your jurisdiction, then you are TOTALLY CORRECT - in that circumstance it would be insane to follow a bankruptcy tactic.  You're totally correct.  But realize that that is *usually NOT the case* in most jurisdictions/situations. Usually you can "get away with" keeping most/whatever assets.

Comment: @sequence After a bankruptcy creditors go to the court, not to you, to get what's owed to them. It's fairly sweeping so it helps get all creditors off your back at one time.

Comment: @DStanley Creditors can't get your unsecured assets, and they definitely can't get your home for unsecured debts, but they can place a lien on it.

Comment: Chapter-7 bankruptcy, or "liquidation", is probably not the most common form, certainly not since the bankruptcy law reform that happened back in 2005.  As part of that law, the bar was substantially raised on whether someone would qualify for chapter-7 or whether they would be forced into chapter-13, "reorganization". Most filers will not qualify for chapter-7.

Comment: You can't emphasize enough the homestead exemption in some locales. In my state, the entire homestead (main residence) is exempt, so you have people who have sunk all their assets into their homes and then declared bk.

Comment: "A bankruptcy will require the borrower to liquidate enough assets to pay off the debt." If one had enough assets to liquidate to pay off the date, one would never declare bankruptcy.

Comment: @shoover If a residence is exempt anyway, why would anyone put any resources in there? In other words, you know that if the debt will be forgiven then there is no need to put any resources towards debt repayment.

Comment: @sequence Say you have purchased a house that is now worth $500k and you have $100k equity in it, plus another $100k of miscellaneous assets. In a state where the entire house is exempt, if you declare bk as-is, the creditors get $100k and you still have $100k equity (and also probably mortgage debt close to $400k). If you take your $100k miscellaneous assets and put it towards the house, then the creditors take $0 and you have $200k equity (and mortgage debt ~$300k). You will likely get foreclosed upon, but that's a separate process.

Comment: @shoover I relied on the complete exemption of homesteads from asset liquidation. But looks like they could still be foreclosed. Now it's clear.

Answer (score 3):

The answer is very simple,

> why would he or she want to file for bankruptcy thus *risking liquidation of his/her assets*? ...

in many cases such folks have little or no assets.

So indeed, you're 100% correct that (in certain jurisdictions) if you, say, own a house, it would be insane to attempt bankruptcy, because it would be stripped from you. You're correct.

Note however that in many jurisdictions, if you go bankrupt you DO NOT have all assets stripped from you.  So, that's the second answer to your question.

Comment: In most jurisdictions there are limits to what a debtor can be stripped of in a bankruptcy. For example, if a house is worth $40k or less then the house would not be liquidated to pay the creditors. The only issue is that rarely a house is worth that little :-)

Comment: @sequence I think the main issue with your focus is that you seem to be assuming that most people own their own homes - when in fact, many people rent.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to D Stanley's good answer on more common ways bankruptcy may occur and some of the protections it can provide, it is also possible that someone may simply have more debt than assets. If your debt is eligible for discharge on bankruptcy (notable exceptions would include some student loan debt depending on jurisdiction), then bankruptcy may immediately increase your net asset position from negative something to near zero. Not a good position to be in after declaring bankruptcy, but 'good' is a relative statement!

Comment: This net position may be more on paper than in reality. For example, if John has a house that is paid off, but more debt than the house is worth, why would John choose to declare bankruptcy and lose his house?

Comment: @sequence See D Stanley's answer above, which talks about more likely bankruptcy scenarios, including where it is not uncommon for someone to have assets worth more than their debt, but may still benefit from declaring bankruptcy. In a case where I own a home worth $300k but have a $400k mortgage [house prices must have really dropped], and I am no longer able to afford the mortgage, I would rather walk away from everything then pay $400k over time for a house worth only $300k. If I am able to pay the monthly mortgage, I might choose to continue to live there if my house is under water.

Comment: I agree that such scenarios exist. But bankruptcy is not a feasible option if you already own a home outright. The homesteading protection is rarely applicable.

Comment: @sequence I agree somewhat with what your are implying: if your home would not be protected in bankruptcy, you own it outright, and have personal debt where your home is not used as security, then you may want to avoid bankruptcy even if you have $1M in debt and only a $200k home, because you might need to sell your house when you might otherwise not have to. But if you rent, maybe own a cheap car, and have minimal personal effects and no savings, and have $45k in credit card debt, that is a scenario where bankruptcy may be beneficial. This is more the scenario I was referring to in my answer.

Comment: One might rather pay the $45k debt with a consolidation loan or something like that. Can be paid off in 2 years even with a menial job. Other than that I agree with you :-)

Comment: @sequence , I notice you are making the same point repeatedly (quite reasonable on the internet!), YES you are CORRECT.  *Depending* on the local jurisdictional laws, YOU ARE CORRECT that bankruptcy would be absurd (in those specific situations you point to).  However, as everyone has mentioned repeatedly, that is RARE.  Usually you can "get away with it".  My impression is that you are "surprised" the law works that way - it's a case of "get used to being surprised"  :O

Comment: @Fattie It is in my understanding that to get away with most of what you own in a bankruptcy one has got to own VERY little.

Comment: @sequence , my impression is your understand then, is simply wrong.  You'd be amazed what you can "get away with".

Comment: @Fattie I saw what assets can be kept in my jurisdiction during a bankruptcy. Very insignificant to put it mildly :-)

Comment: @sequence I'm going to have to echo Fattie here.  In Texas, you can retain a homestead of unlimited value, a vehicle for each licensed household member, and $50k of personal property (twice that if married).  Florida is similarly generous with homestead but less so on personal property, but allows well over $1m in IRAs and 401k (including ROTH).

Comment: @Istanari Looks like bankruptcy laws in the US are generous to the debtor, not so much in Canada.

Comment: @sequence They can be, depending on the jurisdiction.  Each state can be different.  I suggest adding a "country" tag to your question, since it's clearly a critical piece of information.